# Custom Jquery Not Available At Runtime With Dynamicallly Added Html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that looks like this..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>JQM</title>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.css"> 
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function(){
      $('[data-role="list-divider"]').toggle(function(){
        $('.'+$(this).attr('data-link')).addClass('show');
        $(this).children().removeClass('ui-icon-plus').addClass('ui-icon-minus');

      },function(){
        $('.'+$(this).attr('data-link')).removeClass('show');
        $(this).children().removeClass('ui-icon-minus').addClass('ui-icon-plus');
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">

    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   


    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I am adding html in dymanically from the server in the content area. The problem is that when I add the content dynamically, the jquery function that I created statically on the page doesnt engage..

```
<script>
        $(function(){
          $('[data-role="list-divider"]').toggle(function(){
            $('.'+$(this).attr('data-link')).addClass('show');
            $(this).children().removeClass('ui-icon-plus').addClass('ui-icon-minus');

          },function(){
            $('.'+$(this).attr('data-link')).removeClass('show');
            $(this).children().removeClass('ui-icon-minus').addClass('ui-icon-plus');
          });
        });
      </script>
```

If I add the html statically all the code works fine and everything is good. My question is how do I make this jquery available to run once html is added to the page from the server?

I DID THIS AND IT WORKED, is there a more elegant way using .on or is this fine?

```
//got html blob
  deferred.success(function (res) {

   $(function () {
                $('[data-role="list-divider"]').toggle(function () {
                    $('.' + $(this).attr('data-link')).addClass('show');
                    $(this).children().removeClass('ui-icon-plus').addClass('ui-icon-minus');

                }, function () {
                    $('.' + $(this).attr('data-link')).removeClass('show');
                    $(this).children().removeClass('ui-icon-minus').addClass('ui-icon-plus');
                });
            });
 });
```

Comment: which version of jquery is you using?

Comment: @ssilas I am using 1.8..the jquery works fine if I simply put in a blob of html without loading it dynamically. The problem is when I load the html dynamically the custom jquery wont engage.

Comment: If by dynamically loading the content you mean via an ajax call you need to run that jquery on ajax.success or else it wont' see your html.

Comment: @Jisaak I am loading the html via ajax. Can you show me some code on what you mean?

Comment: @Jisaak your right that worked can you please post so I can create you. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the jquery is currently ran when the document is ready and your content is not loaded yet it won't find the elements and wire-up the events. Adding your script to the `ajax.success` should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

looking at your code, I don't see where you're loading the content dynamically. But if you want that script to run. You should try a document.ready() in front of that script

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind event handlers to elements that haven't been created. Check out this:

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use jquery `.On()` method to attach even handlers to contents dynamically added to pages. Check this - [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Some thing lik this might work (didn't test) :-

```
  $(function(){
      $('[data-role="list-divider"]').on('toggle' ,function(event){
        $('.'+$(this).attr('data-link')).addClass('show');
        $(this).children().removeClass('ui-icon-plus').addClass('ui-icon-minus');

      },function(event){
        $('.'+$(this).attr('data-link')).removeClass('show');
        $(this).children().removeClass('ui-icon-minus').addClass('ui-icon-plus');
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $(function(){
      $(document).on('toggle', '[data-role="list-divider"]', function(){
        $('.'+$(this).attr('data-link')).addClass('show');
        $(this).children().removeClass('ui-icon-plus').addClass('ui-icon-minus');

      },function(){
        $('.'+$(this).attr('data-link')).removeClass('show');
        $(this).children().removeClass('ui-icon-minus').addClass('ui-icon-plus');
      });
    });
```

Haven't tested it though. For on('click') this usually works.

What you do is you bind the 'toggle' trigger to the whole document ( $(document) ) and then check on what element is was triggered. This way you can detect elements that were created after the initialization of the DOM.